# Is the use of word-'both' with plural nouns correct in the sentence below

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Sentence => 'Two or more vectors are said to be equal vectors when both of their magnitudes and directions are same.'

In the above sentence I have used the word-'both' with the words- 'magnitudes' and 'directions' which are in plural form because the sentence is referring to two vectors which each have some magnitude and a direction.

Please also tell if there is an other error or if the sentence can be written in another way.

Comment: Each vector has one magnitude and one direction. Does 'both' refer to 'both vectors'? No, because you say "two or more." It isn't really necessary anyway: "Two or more vectors are said to be equal vectors when their magnitudes and directions are same." IMO you would have to rephrase slightly to use the word 'both': "Two or more vectors are said to be equal vectors when both their magnitude and direction are same."

Comment: I recommend a slightly different formulation: _... when both their magnitudes and their directions are the same.'_ Leave out the _of_, and add _their_ before _directions_ and _the_ before _same_.

Comment: Yes I noticed the missing 'the' too late to edit.

Comment: Two or more vectors are said to be equal when they are the same.